# Python Selenium Do-While Loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to complete a do-while loop with the below code. We are waiting for a report to process, and it only shows on the webpage once completed and after clicking the retrieve button. The code,

```
# Go to list and click retrieve
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#j_idt40Lbl").click()
time.sleep(20) # takes a while for their side to run
retrieve = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#tab_reportList\:listPgFrm\:listPgRetrBtn")
retrieve.click() ### Do this action ###
time.sleep(5)
retrieve.click()
time.sleep(5)
retrieve.click()
time.sleep(3)

# Click report file
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#tab_reportList\:listPgFrm\:listDataTable_0\:0\:reportLink"))).click() 
### Until this is visible ###
```

Comment: does element `#tab_reportList\:listPgFrm\:listDataTable_0\:0\:reportLink` is presented there even before it becomes visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the element finally becoming visible is not initially presents on the page your code can be something like this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#j_idt40Lbl").click()
time.sleep(20)
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#tab_reportList\:listPgFrm\:listPgRetrBtn").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    if driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#tab_reportList\:listPgFrm\:listDataTable_0\:0\:reportLink"):
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#tab_reportList\:listPgFrm\:listDataTable_0\:0\:reportLink"))).click()
        break
```

Hardcoded sleeps of 5 and 20 seconds are not looking good. If possibly they should be changed by Expected Conditions explicit waits

Comment: `if(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#tab_reportList\:listPgFrm\:listDataTable_0\:0\:reportLink")):` - In python we do not need those if parentheses.

Comment: Right, I just copied the original code to make it working. But I will correct that, thanks